# CSS beginner: Responsive style not dispplaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I am a complete beginner in CSS. For my course I have to code a style for just one page (Mockup for tablet is attached: [Mockup-tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmTxN.png)

as I a limited to 2 links). However my div elements are not displaying correctly, one is on the second line on desktop instead of being inline, and the tablet style is wrong too, but I can't figure out why.
It has been suggested that I use a dedicated div enclosing my elements, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOvbeq

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Our menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<br/><br/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4" "col-md-6" "col-xs-12"><div class="pinktitle">Chicken</div><p><br/><br/><br/>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus.</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4" "col-md-6" "col-xs-12"><div class="redtitle">Beef</div><p><br/><br/><br/>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus.</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4" "col-md-12" "col-xs-12"><div class="yellowtitle">Sushi</div><p><br/><br/><br/>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus.</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/********** Base styles **********/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  }

.pinktitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ffb6c1;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
 }
 .redtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #dc143c;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
 }
 .yellowtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ffd700;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
 }
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: black;
}

/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Many thanks if you can help

So after all your answers, I edited the row element like this but it still doesn't work:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Is there an other div to modify?

Comment: Your codepen link is broken...

Comment: Are you placing the `style` OUTSIDE of the HTML tags? Because it should be a linked file (.css) or as you have it now but inside of the HEAD tag.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you need to do sth like this: https://jsfiddle.net/019zzvd7/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use bootstrap instead of writing all col percentages. So these are predefined in bootstrap. After adding to bootstrap you can write your code like that:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-lg-6"><div class="pinktitle">Chicken....</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"><div class="redtitle">Beef...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12"><div class="yellowtitle">Sushi...</div>
  </div>
```

For more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: "Better"... wow. Well... better is obviously not a set value, then. It's not "better", nor "simpler" - it's just different, and not at all that very good.

Comment: Hello, I am not allowed for this exercise to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Sophie, first of all, just delete extra quotes in div's classes:
instead `<div class="col-lg-4" "col-md-6" "col-xs-12">`
change to `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">`

[Jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/2wmcwu2m/)

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip! It is still  not working however.

Comment: @Sophie, nothing changed at all? in this case, you'd add `box-sizing: border-box;` into `.col-.....` media-queries. I think, it happened because this property didn't applied

Comment: Hello, that was it. I re-added the border box element in each div and it's working now. Many thanks!

Comment: If it was helpfull for you, please, check the answer, it could be helpfull for other!

Answer (score 0):

you have not factored the border around your div which is 1px, that may be a small difference but that's the reason for pushing your content to the next line.

Comment: I just corrected it (see code above), but it doesn't work better. Maybe there is an other div to correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have hit enter in html file and closing each div and it takes as a space.

Just remove newline from your html and it will work.

Example Fiddle to justify the answer. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6r0zsdzy/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><div class="pinktitle">Chicken</div><p><br/><br/><br/>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus.</p></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><div class="redtitle">Beef</div><p><br/><br/><br/>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus.</p></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="yellowtitle">Sushi</div><p><br/><br/><br/>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus.</p></div>
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't change, one box is still on the next line.

Comment: @Sophie : Did you visit the fiddle who's link I have included in answer?

Comment: Hello, yes I checked but it wasn't this. I re-added the border box element as propossed above, and it works now. Thanks for your help.